# How to know if setupUi has already been called

Tags: c++, qt

I need to know if a widget has already received the `setupUi` *"blessing"*  and if it has already constructed all the sub-widgeets.

Is there a method for this? Or should I track in the code whether this has been previously done?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the widget empty ?
If not you could just delay its creation and always call the `setupUi` at the same time you create your object, then you can check the pointer to see if it has been set up or not.

```
MyClass::MyClass() : m_ui(nullptr) 
{}

MyClass::initialize()
{
    if (m_ui == nullptr)
    {
        m_ui = new UiClass;
        m_ui->setupUi(this);
    }
    // ...
}
```

It depends on your usecase, on why/when you need to know if setupUi has been called.

Comment: That was so easy... Never used pointers for ui stuff. Might be nicer to use QPointer to avoid initialization

Answer (score 2):

You could track it yourself, either with some kind of global variable that you check before calling the function, or by a local static variable inside the function. Or you could use [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) which will handle the checking for you.